# How to maximize MATLAB's GPU utility?

Tags: matlab, performance, parallel-processing, gpu

I've surveyed my GPU's performance against itself and the CPU for varying matrix sizes, and found the opposite of what most GPU literature suggests: the GPU's computing advantage *diminishes* with array size. Code, results, & specs shown below. Noteworthy observations:

1. GPU utility remains sub-10%, according to Task Manager
2. ~(50%, 20%) = (RAM, CPU) usage for large (K > 9000) arrays
3. Considerable speed ratio drop's observed for around K > 8000
4. Splitting the K > 8000 (= 9000) `Xga` matrix into four *increases* vectorized speed two-fold
5. My GPU ranks far higher among GPUs than my CPU ([#24](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1070-vs-Nvidia-Titan-RTX/3609vsm664199) vs. [#174](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-vs-AMD-Ryzen-TR-2990WX/m211019vsm560423)); it thus seems an on-par CPU would *outperform* the GPU for larger arrays
6. Last pic's GPU vs. CPU benchmark supports **(5)**; GPU isn't as vastly superior as expected

What's the culprit - is my code, or MATLAB, or hardware configuration under-utilizing the GPU? How to find out and resolve it?

---

```
%% CODE: centroid indexing in K-means algorithm
    % size(X) = [16000, 3]
    % size(centroids) = [K, 3]
    % Xga = gpuArray(single(X)); cga = gpuArray(single(centroids));
    % Speed ratio = t2/t1, if t2 > t1 - else, t1/t2

%% TIMING
    f1 = fasterFunction(...);
    f2 = slowerFunction(...);
    t1 = gputimeit(f1)  % OR timeit(f1) for non-GPU arrays
    t2 = timeit(f2)     % OR gputimeit(f2) for GPU arrays

%% FUNCTIONS
function out = vecHammer(X, c, K, m)
  [~, out] = min(reshape(permute(sum((X-permute(c,[3 2 1])).^2,2),[1 2 3]),m,K),[],2);
end

function out = forvecHammer(X, c, m)
out = zeros(m,1);
  for j=1:m
    [~,out(j)] = min(sum(((X(j,:))'-c').^2));
  end
end

function out = forforHammer(X,c,m,K)
out = zeros(m,1); idxtemp = zeros(K,1);
  for i=1:m
    for j=1:K
      idxtemp(j) = sum((X(i,:)-c(j,:)).^2,2);
    end
  [~, out(i)] = min(idxtemp);
  end
end
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to read Matlab code, but would it be fair to characterize the performance of code for graphs 1-4 to be *bound by memory bandwidth*, as there seems to be little computation done per array element? As for the last graph, consumer GPUs (like the GTX 1070) have low throughput for double-precision operations, so the observed matrix-multiply performance (*compute bound*) looks as expected to me. Wikipedia lists the GTX 1070 as having between 180 and 202 DP GFLOPS, depending on core frequency (this GPU has dynamic clocking).

Comment: For computation bound by memory throughput, you would expect about factor 7 advantage for the GPU (max. theoretical bandwidth of i7-7700hq is 37.5 GB/sec, max. theoretical bandwidth of GTX 1070 is 250 GB/sec). These numbers will differ somewhat depending on speed of DRAM installed for the CPU and any vendor overclocking for the GPU; for sufficiently small arrays one would also expect cache-based speedups on CPU.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the response; good observation on double-precision - I've added the single-precision test result. To briefly explain the code: rows of X = (x, y, z) coords of datapoints; c = same, but for another set of points. The goal is to find the c (centroid) that's closest to a given datapoint in X. The 'sum' in vecHammer adds squares of differences; 'permute' transforms c into a [1 x 3 x K] (3D) array, allowing subtracting every row of c from every row of X in one operation - and second 'permute' for 3D -> 2D.

Comment: @njuffa As for memory throughput-bound computing, unsure; Xga = gpuArray(X) transfers X onto the GPU BEFORE any computing - and this time was excluded from the performance tests. (Unless you don't refer to transfer time; I'm unfamiliar with 'memory throughput') Whatever the case, I fail to see how GPU's self-boasting for handling big data is justified; while a seven-fold advantage is significant, it still falls below often-cited figures ranging hundreds. 

Further, the single-precision test showed a 26-fold advantage; how come that didn't reflect in the GPU vs. CPU-vectorized test?

Comment: From what I have seen, 100x speed-ups reported were not self-boasting by the GPU vendor, but unscrupulous researchers peddling papers. It is easy to do by comparing scalar single-threaded CPU implementation versus fully optimized GPU implementation. Generally, for *application-level speedup*, the high-end GPU vs high-end CPU advantage should be expected to be in 2x to 10x range, with average around 5x. Here you are looking at building blocks so the range could be bigger. Since I don't understand what your code does (not a MATLAB user) I will refrain from further comments.

Comment: @njuffa Found a way to considerably offset the dropoff; see new figure. Further, entire plot's scaled by ~2 relative to the first due to supplying single-precision arrays to the CPU, which I apparently missed at first. Is this improvement and its method particularly informative? --



Further, could the hard-drive be the culprit? Trying the second-to-last plot for numel = 1e9 yields memory error, and task manager shows SSD maxed out; I run MATLAB on an SSD with 23GB free space - the HDD has 800. Lastly, GPU utility still remains sub-10% across all tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable answer is - the data was simply too small, and only so much can be parallelized; my GPU pulls a gigabyte dataset with a few percentage points - this one barely measured up to 10MB.